# Why do I fail Django migration in heroku server while succeeding in local server?

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I have deployed my Django project to Heroku, and now trying to migrate the database. I have everything working fine in my local sever. Then I tried to run the commands in heroku, as below.

`python manage.py makemigrations`
This worked fine.

```
Migrations for 'app_name':
  contents\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Book   
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Content
```

Then of course, I tried : 
`git add .`
`git commit -m "migration"`
 `git push heroku master` 
 `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name`
But then I got this error `CommandError: App 'app_name' does not have migrations.`


 Strange thing is, after running `python manage.py migrate`, everything works fine in my local server. It's only the heroku server where the error occurs.
I've done some research for possible issues, none of which were relevant to mine.
For example I do have **init**.py in the migrations folder inside `app_name` directory. Also, I've tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate` as well as `heroku run python manage.py migrate app_name` but neither worked.
I'm very confused. What do you think is the problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Ram running `makemigrations` on remote environment, not your local development one is almost always a bad idea. Your migrations should be created locally and commited with your code.  @Ryan can you run `git status` in your local directory and confirm you've properly added all the files to the commit? Have you pulled the new code on heroku?

Comment: @Ram, there is _never_ a valid reason to run `makemigrations` on Heroku. That should only be done as part of _development_. Run `migrate` on Heroku to apply existing migrations.

Comment: Maybe check if the migration files are actually committed? It could be included in your `.gitignore` or something

Comment: @GwynBleidD and Chris I didn't knew that earlier. Thanks for letting me know.